# Receiving and listening changes using Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to be notified when a particular characteristic changes on the device BLE, I used the methodes onCharacteristicChanged and setCharacteristicNotification()  but no change occurence when I change the action of the device connected.

Any example to receive change of the device With BLE ?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Did you use descriptor.setValue() ?

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
       UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification